# How to mount macOS partition as read-write for all files/folders?

Tags: 16.04, permissions, mount, hfs+

I have dual-booted my Mac with Ubuntu 16.04 (LTS) and macOS High Sierra (on an HFS+ drive). When I attempt to mount my macOS partition using

```
sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sda2 /mnt
```

the mount succeeds, but when I try to access my user's files, I find that they are locked, with `700` permissions.

How can I mount my macOS partition such that I'm able to read and write to these folders without permanently changing permissions?